# Simulation of a hydraulic system

Tags: modelica

I try to simulate a hydraulic machine in Ansys Twinbuilder 2021 R1 with Modelica language.

The whole system is in the following image;

[image]

Firstly I tried to divide the whole system into the subsystems. And I simulated the subsystems of pumpraum-1, pumpraum-2, pumpraum-3, outlet-components. And the subsystems work individually without any problem. Then I tried to compile the subsystems into the whole system. Then the simulation doesn`t proceed smoothly. It stops at any timestep and doesnt continue to the end of the simulation. What could be reason of that? How can I understand where is the problem in my whole system?

The code of my model is as follows;

```
model HD_3Kolben_bsp
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    replaceable package medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater( );
    Real opening_HP;
    Real opening_LP;
    constant Modelica.SIunits.AbsolutePressure patm = 1e5;
    Real opening_HP_2;
    Real opening_LP_2;
    Real opening_HP_3;
    Real opening_LP_3;
    constant Modelica.SIunits.Frequency freq = 46;
    //Component(s)
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system (p_ambient = 101325);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 0);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume1 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile1 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile1 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_Ein_ND (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Einlass (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position;
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position2;
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile2 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP_2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile2 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP_2);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume2 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine2 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 7/(3*freq));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit2 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben2 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sensors.PositionSensor Position3;
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear NDVentile3 (
        dp_nominal = 94.35,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_LP_3);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_ND_CV_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Valves.ValveLinear HDVentile3 (
        dp_nominal = 95,
        m_flow_nominal = 0.05867441,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        opening = opening_HP_3);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe_CV_HD_3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume ClosedVolume3 (
        V = 0.000005/2,
        nPorts = 3,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine3 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = freq,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = +Modelica.Constants.pi/2.01,
        startTime = 14/(3*freq));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit3 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Kolben3 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary1 (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe1 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary boundary2 (p = 4e5, redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater, nPorts = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe2 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.002,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe3 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe4 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe5 (
        length = 0.005,
        diameter = 0.0055,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume2 (
        V = 3.13e-6,
        nPorts = 4,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        use_portsData = false);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe (length = 0.001, diameter = 0.002, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe6 (length = 0.001, diameter = 0.002, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.StaticPipe pipe7 (length = 0.001, diameter = 0.002, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe10_steig (
        length = 0.003,
        diameter = 0.002721,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe9_steig (
        length = 0.008,
        diameter = 0.00598,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe8 (
        length = 5,
        diameter = 0.0057,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice4 (diameter = 0.00452, zeta = 3.5, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Duese_2 (
        length = 0.0082,
        diameter = 0.0042,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Duese_3 (
        length = 0.018,
        diameter = 0.00452,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Duese_4 (
        length = 0.0002,
        diameter = 0.0005,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe Duese_1 (
        length = 0.393,
        diameter = 0.0074,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pistole_3 (
        length = 0.02,
        diameter = 0.004,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice2 (diameter = 0.005, zeta = 0.98, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pistole_1 (
        length = 0.041,
        diameter = 0.0057,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Fittings.SimpleGenericOrifice orifice1 (diameter = 0.005, zeta = 1, redeclare package Medium = medium);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pistole_2 (
        length = 0.269,
        diameter = 0.0069,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        nNodes = 1,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b);
    Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe pipe9 (
        length = 0.24,
        diameter = 0.005,
        redeclare package Medium = medium,
        roughness = 2.5E-5,
        modelStructure = Modelica.Fluid.Types.ModelStructure.av_b,
        nNodes = 1);
    Modelica.Fluid.Sources.FixedBoundary Auslass (p = patm, redeclare package Medium = medium, nPorts = 1);


equation
    if der(Position.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP=1;  
           opening_HP=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP=0;
           opening_HP=1;
     end if; 
    if der(Position2.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP_2=1;  
           opening_HP_2=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP_2=0;
           opening_HP_2=1;
     end if;
     if der(Position3.s)>=0 then 
           opening_LP_3=1;  
           opening_HP_3=0; 
     else 
           opening_LP_3=0;
           opening_HP_3=1;
     end if;
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Posit1.flange, Kolben1.flange);
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_1.port_b, HDVentile1.port_a);
    connect(NDVentile1.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_1.port_a);
    connect(Einlass.ports[1], pipe_Ein_ND.port_a);
    connect(Posit1.flange, Position.flange);
    connect(Position2.flange, Posit2.flange);
    connect(NDVentile2.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_2.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile2.port_a, pipe_CV_HD_2.port_b);
    connect(Sine2.y, Posit2.s_ref);
    connect(Posit2.flange, Kolben2.flange);
    connect(Position3.flange, Posit3.flange);
    connect(NDVentile3.port_b, pipe_ND_CV_3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile3.port_a, pipe_CV_HD_3.port_b);
    connect(Sine3.y, Posit3.s_ref);
    connect(Posit3.flange, Kolben3.flange);
    connect(boundary1.ports[1], pipe1.port_a);
    connect(boundary2.ports[1], pipe2.port_a);
    connect(pipe_Ein_ND.port_b, NDVentile1.port_a);
    connect(pipe1.port_b, NDVentile2.port_a);
    connect(pipe2.port_b, NDVentile3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile1.port_b, pipe3.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile2.port_b, pipe4.port_a);
    connect(HDVentile3.port_b, pipe5.port_a);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_1.port_b, ClosedVolume1.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_1.port_a, ClosedVolume1.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_2.port_b, ClosedVolume2.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_2.port_a, ClosedVolume2.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe_ND_CV_3.port_b, ClosedVolume3.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe_CV_HD_3.port_a, ClosedVolume3.ports[3]);
    connect(pipe3.port_b, volume2.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe4.port_b, volume2.ports[2]);
    connect(pipe5.port_b, volume2.ports[3]);
    connect(Kolben1.ports[1], pipe.port_a);
    connect(pipe.port_b, ClosedVolume1.ports[1]);
    connect(Kolben2.ports[1], pipe6.port_a);
    connect(pipe6.port_b, ClosedVolume2.ports[1]);
    connect(Kolben3.ports[1], pipe7.port_a);
    connect(pipe7.port_b, ClosedVolume3.ports[1]);
    connect(pipe10_steig.port_a, Duese_3.port_b);
    connect(pipe9_steig.port_b, Duese_2.port_a);
    connect(pipe9_steig.port_a, Duese_1.port_b);
    connect(pipe10_steig.port_b, orifice4.port_a);
    connect(pistole_3.port_a, pistole_2.port_b);
    connect(pistole_1.port_b, pistole_2.port_a);
    connect(pipe8.port_b, pistole_1.port_a);
    connect(pipe8.port_a, orifice2.port_b);
    connect(orifice4.port_b, Duese_4.port_a);
    connect(Duese_2.port_b, Duese_3.port_a);
    connect(Duese_4.port_b, Auslass.ports[1]);
    connect(Duese_1.port_a, orifice1.port_b);
    connect(pistole_3.port_b, orifice1.port_a);
    connect(orifice2.port_a, pipe9.port_b);
    connect(pipe9.port_a, volume2.ports[4]);
end  HD_3Kolben_bsp;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Dymola, and after reducing the relative tolerance of the solver, I'm getting this:

> Model error - differentiated if-then-else was not continuous:  (if
> time < 0.050724637681159424 then 0 else Sine2.amplitude*sin(289.02652413026095*(time-0.050724637681159424)+Sine2.phase))
> Value jumped from 0 to 0.00556683.

This error can be overcome by setting `Posit2.exact = false`. But then a follow-up error emerges, likely due to the quick change or an inconsistent overall system. This is difficult to judge without knowing the model in detail. So I'll leave that to somebody else to solve.

Besides that there are some issues with initialization, but they seem to be rather minor:

> IF97 medium function called with too low pressure p = -35428.5 Pa <= 611.657 Pa (triple point pressure)
> Failed condition: p > 611.657

Regarding the second comment:

The initialization issue should be solvable by setting (the important) variables from the following list. The list actually contains variables for which the simulation environment has to guess initial values, as they are not specified.

```
Assuming fixed start value for the continuous states:
ClosedVolume1.medium.h(start = ClosedVolume1.h_start)
ClosedVolume1.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
ClosedVolume2.medium.h(start = ClosedVolume2.h_start)
ClosedVolume2.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
ClosedVolume3.medium.h(start = ClosedVolume3.h_start)
ClosedVolume3.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
Duese_1.mediums[1].h(start = Duese_1.h_start)
Duese_1.mediums[1].p(start = Duese_1.ps_start[1])
Duese_2.mediums[1].h(start = Duese_2.h_start)
Duese_2.mediums[1].p(start = Duese_2.ps_start[1])
Duese_3.mediums[1].h(start = Duese_3.h_start)
Duese_3.mediums[1].p(start = Duese_3.ps_start[1])
Duese_4.mediums[1].h(start = Duese_4.h_start)
Duese_4.mediums[1].p(start = Duese_4.ps_start[1])
Kolben1.medium.h(start = Kolben1.h_start)
Kolben1.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
Kolben2.medium.h(start = Kolben2.h_start)
Kolben2.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
Kolben3.medium.h(start = Kolben3.h_start)
Kolben3.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
pipe1.mediums[1].h(start = pipe1.h_start)
pipe1.mediums[2].h(start = pipe1.h_start)
pipe1.mediums[2].p(start = pipe1.ps_start[2])
pipe2.mediums[1].h(start = pipe2.h_start)
pipe2.mediums[2].h(start = pipe2.h_start)
pipe2.mediums[2].p(start = pipe2.ps_start[2])
pipe3.mediums[1].h(start = pipe3.h_start)
pipe3.mediums[1].p(start = pipe3.ps_start[1])
pipe3.mediums[2].h(start = pipe3.h_start)
pipe3.mediums[2].p(start = pipe3.ps_start[2])
pipe4.mediums[1].h(start = pipe4.h_start)
pipe4.mediums[1].p(start = pipe4.ps_start[1])
pipe4.mediums[2].h(start = pipe4.h_start)
pipe4.mediums[2].p(start = pipe4.ps_start[2])
pipe5.mediums[1].h(start = pipe5.h_start)
pipe5.mediums[1].p(start = pipe5.ps_start[1])
pipe5.mediums[2].h(start = pipe5.h_start)
pipe5.mediums[2].p(start = pipe5.ps_start[2])
pipe8.mediums[1].h(start = pipe8.h_start)
pipe8.mediums[1].p(start = pipe8.ps_start[1])
pipe9.mediums[1].h(start = pipe9.h_start)
pipe9_steig.mediums[1].h(start = pipe9_steig.h_start)
pipe9_steig.mediums[1].p(start = pipe9_steig.ps_start[1])
pipe10_steig.mediums[1].h(start = pipe10_steig.h_start)
pipe10_steig.mediums[1].p(start = pipe10_steig.ps_start[1])
pipe_CV_HD_1.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_CV_HD_1.h_start)
pipe_CV_HD_1.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_CV_HD_1.h_start)
pipe_CV_HD_1.mediums[2].p(start = pipe_CV_HD_1.ps_start[2])
pipe_CV_HD_2.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_CV_HD_2.h_start)
pipe_CV_HD_2.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_CV_HD_2.h_start)
pipe_CV_HD_2.mediums[2].p(start = pipe_CV_HD_2.ps_start[2])
pipe_CV_HD_3.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_CV_HD_3.h_start)
pipe_CV_HD_3.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_CV_HD_3.h_start)
pipe_CV_HD_3.mediums[2].p(start = pipe_CV_HD_3.ps_start[2])
pipe_Ein_ND.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_Ein_ND.h_start)
pipe_Ein_ND.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_Ein_ND.h_start)
pipe_Ein_ND.mediums[2].p(start = pipe_Ein_ND.ps_start[2])
pipe_ND_CV_1.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_ND_CV_1.h_start)
pipe_ND_CV_1.mediums[1].p(start = pipe_ND_CV_1.ps_start[1])
pipe_ND_CV_1.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_ND_CV_1.h_start)
pipe_ND_CV_2.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_ND_CV_2.h_start)
pipe_ND_CV_2.mediums[1].p(start = pipe_ND_CV_2.ps_start[1])
pipe_ND_CV_2.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_ND_CV_2.h_start)
pipe_ND_CV_3.mediums[1].h(start = pipe_ND_CV_3.h_start)
pipe_ND_CV_3.mediums[1].p(start = pipe_ND_CV_3.ps_start[1])
pipe_ND_CV_3.mediums[2].h(start = pipe_ND_CV_3.h_start)
pistole_1.mediums[1].h(start = pistole_1.h_start)
pistole_1.mediums[1].p(start = pistole_1.ps_start[1])
pistole_2.mediums[1].h(start = pistole_2.h_start)
pistole_2.mediums[1].p(start = pistole_2.ps_start[1])
pistole_3.mediums[1].h(start = pistole_3.h_start)
pistole_3.mediums[1].p(start = pistole_3.ps_start[1])
volume2.medium.h(start = volume2.h_start)
volume2.medium.p(start = 101325.0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for these informations. Could you give more information about the issue with initialization, why does it occur or how can I avoid this error?

Comment: Apart from that, is there a way to see these errors also in Twinbuilder? I dont use Dymola. Therefore I can`t see such errors.

Comment: Regarding 1: I edited the post to give some further information.
Regarding 2: I don't have Twinbuilder, so I can't help with that, sorry...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wrote these equations in the initial equation section. It throws me an error for each state. I get such an error:```cannot find the declaration for ClosedVolume1.mediumh()```. How can I define the states for these components?

Comment: You need to make sure the initial equation is put in the correct level of hierarchy. If you are using `ClosedVolume1.mediumh()` (I think it should be `ClosedVolume1.medium.h(start=...`) this should be in the top level of the model. Additionally - specifically for `ClosedVolume.h` - there actually is a parameter in the _Initialization_ tab called `h_start`.

Comment: Thanks. If I give the initizialization value ```h(start = ClosedVolume1.h_start)``` for ```ClosedVolume``` in Initialization tab ```h_start```, it throws the error saying: ```HD_3Kolben_bsp, Line 38 : Circularity in binding expression of parameter: ClosedVolume1.h_start = ClosedVolume1.h_start```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you correctly. In the parameter window you should give literal values or an expression that can be computed from parameters.